# How to record a macro in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: hotkeys, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, animation

I want to create a following macro in PowerPoint 2007:
Add specific animation to selected object, pressing hotkey.

I already enabled Developer page, but I can't find how to record my actions and assign hot key.

Answer (score 3):

The macro recorder is **not available** in Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007. Instead, you can use Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) to create or edit macros. To create or edit a macro by using VBA, do the following:

1. On the Developer tab, in the Code
   group, click Macros.
2. In the Macro dialog box, in the
   Macro name box, type a name for the
   macro.
3. In the Macro in list, click the
   template or the presentation that
   you want to store the macro in.
4. In the Description box, type a
   description for the macro.
5. Click Create to open Visual Basic
   for Applications.

Source: MS Powerpoint 2007 Help File

---

### Why was the record macro feature removed from Powerpoint 2007?

According to Steve Rindsberg, PPT MVP, macro recorder wasn't all that
great even in 2002/2003. It missed all animation stuff and other things.
With all the changes to the object model in 2007, bringing the recorder up to
speed would've taken a LOT of work. They probably decided the resources would
be better spent on other features and rather than deal with a lot of tech
support problems with the macro recorder, and they removed it. ([Tech-archive](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Office/microsoft.public.powerpoint/2008-07/msg00845.html))

Comment: I want to record my action, but not to input VBA code and want also to set up hotkey

Comment: Unfortunately, you are not allowed to do that in Powerpoint 2007 as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Start by enabling the developer tool bar: office button | PowerPoint options | Popular | Show Developer Tab In Ribbon.

Then follow the other answer.

Comment: this is not what I want. I don't want to input VBA code, I want to record my actions (animation setting specifically) and set up hotkey for it. I don't know how to do this in VBA editor

Comment: @sergdev: No macro recorder => your only option is to write VBA.